# How to place toplevel window in center of parent window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to place a toplevel window in the center of its parent window. I tried

```
window = Tk()
top = Toplevel(window)
x = window.winfo_x() + window.winfo_width() // 2 - top.winfo_width() // 2
y = window.winfo_y() + window.winfo_height() // 2 - top.winfo_height() // 2
top.geometry(f"+{x}+{y}")
```

But it seems that it's ignoring the `- top.winfo_width() // 2` and `- top.winfo_height // 2` parts.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When those `winfo_width()` and `winfo_height()` are executed, those windows' layout have not yet confirmed, so you may get the size 1x1.  Try calling `wait_visibility()` (waits until the window is visible) on both windows before calling those `winfo_xxxx()`.

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry('800x600')
window.wait_visibility()

top = Toplevel(window)
top.wait_visibility()

x = window.winfo_x() + window.winfo_width()//2 - top.winfo_width()//2
y = window.winfo_y() + window.winfo_height()//2 - top.winfo_height()//2
top.geometry(f"+{x}+{y}")

window.mainloop()
```